# How to get the note from midi file using android-midi-lib?

Tags: android, midi

I've tried out the example that the android-midi-lib supplied to get the midi event, and I want to get the pitch for each note in NoteOn event, but it seems that the result is not what I want.  And I can't figure out what information has been returned in the LogCat.

I don't know what's information in `XXXX (YY): NoteOn`.  The analyzed midi file is 'Mary had a little lamb', so I don't think either XXXX or YY will be the note.  Here is the returned info.  Please help,thanks!

**Update:**  `XXXX (YY): NoteOn` is not about the pitch of a note, I figure out that the number 25 in the returning message means 1/4 beat. And a pair of XXXX(455) and XXXX(25) represents a note.  And the later XXXX has some arithmetic relations with the former XXXX, but I still don't know what XXXX stands for.

```
12-11 23:21:22.947: I/System.out(2303): Warning: GenericMetaEvent used because type (33) wasn't recognized or unexpected data length (1) for type.
12-11 23:21:23.288: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All Started!
12-11 23:21:23.307: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 0 (0): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:23.338: I/Choreographer(2303): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:21:23.597: I/Choreographer(2303): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 23:21:23.769: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 455 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:23.797: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 480 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:24.271: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 935 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:24.292: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 960 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:24.771: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 1415 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:24.791: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 1440 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:25.272: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 1895 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:25.293: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 1920 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:25.771: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 2375 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:25.797: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 2400 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:26.268: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 2855 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:26.288: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 2880 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:26.767: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 3335 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:27.295: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 3840 (505): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:27.772: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 4295 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:27.798: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 4320 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:28.268: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 4775 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:28.296: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 4800 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:28.773: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 5255 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:29.288: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 5760 (505): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:29.765: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 6215 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:29.793: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 6240 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:30.270: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 6695 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:30.298: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 6720 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:30.769: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 7175 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:31.297: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 7680 (505): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:31.767: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 8135 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:31.797: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 8160 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:32.266: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 8615 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:32.293: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 8640 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:32.770: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 9095 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:32.799: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 9120 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:33.268: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 9575 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:33.297: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 9600 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:33.767: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 10055 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:33.794: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 10080 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:34.273: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 10535 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:34.291: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 10560 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:34.768: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 11015 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:34.797: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 11040 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:35.267: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 11495 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:35.292: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 11520 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:35.769: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 11975 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:35.798: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 12000 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:36.267: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 12455 (455): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:36.297: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 12480 (25): NoteOn
12-11 23:21:36.767: I/System.out(2303): Listener For All received event: 12935 (455): NoteOn
```

Comment: "… so I don't think either XXXX or YY will be the note" why?

Comment: @nonchip You can see the following example.
12480 (25): NoteOn
12935 (455): NoteOn
The first number is increasing, and the second number is always repeating, the midi file I loaded is Mary had a little lamb, there is no relation between this two numbers and the midi file.

Answer (score 1):

The [NoteOn class](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib/blob/master/src/com/leff/midi/event/NoteOn.java) has a member function `getNoteValue()`.

Comment: Thanks, but yes, I know.  The question is I don't know how to use it, since in my case the input is a midiFile, it isn't the note that I've inserted as a NoteOn value.  The getNoteValue() should be used after setNoteValue(int p), right?(I may misunderstand it)  But how can I get the value of p?  If there is a way to get p, the getNoteValue() will be useless, since I've got the note.

Comment: Of course the note value is the note value! The library created this object from the values in the MIDI file.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I couldn't get your point.  You meant that the note in the **midi file** (not the inserted note) can be stored by using NodeOn class?  But how can the note value be set into a NodeOn variable?

Comment: What do you mean with "inserted"? You haven't shown any code that inserts anything. The library reads the MIDI file, construct the appropriate event objects, and calls your listener with each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, CL.  I did not inserted anything.  I just don't know how to get the note by using this lib...how stupid am I...  
But I just found one using JMusic.jar and it works.  How exciting about that!!!  You know, I spent a day on the problem and failed to write my own method.  And here is the method that I searched, hope that it will help someone who have the same problem like me  :) http://explodingart.com/jmusic/jmdemos/SimpleAnalysis.java